# Typeof object is not function even though it implements [[Call]]

Tags: javascript, types, typeof

I am new to Javascript, so apologies if this has a trivial answer.

According to the ECMAScript language specification, if the return type of a val is `Object (implements [[Call]])` then the result is the string "function". What I don't understand is why in the following code, the type of the newly created object is not "function":

```
function FunctionCreator(){}

FunctionCreator.prototype = Function.prototype;

let obj = new FunctionCreator();

console.log(typeof obj); // object
console.log(obj.call); // ƒ call() { [native code] }
```

The [[Call]] method is defined in Function.prototype, the same way I believe it is defined for a normal function, and yet typeof returns object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` isn't a function, it's an object created via the `new` operator. `FunctionCreator` is a function, but it doesn't create functions. Just making its prototype `Function.prototype` doesn't make what it creates functions, it just makes the object inherit properties that can't be usefully used, because it's not a function.

> The [[Call]] method is defined in Function.prototype...

This may be what you're misunderstanding. `Function.prototype` has a [`call`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.call) method, but that is **not** the [[[Call]] internal method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-6). It's just a method called `call`. [[Call]] is not accessible externally (and depending on the implementation of the JavaScript engine, it may not literally exist; it's a specification mechanism).

To create a function, you use a function declaration, function expression, method definition, etc. ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/22173438#22173438)); or if you can't avoid them and you know the dangers associated with them, `eval` or `new Function`.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix @PoulKruijt!